# Actual and Formal Argument

Tags: java

So, I;m following a tutorial and I followed it exactly but when I test, it throws a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -   constructor Main in class spritesheet.Main cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.awt.Color
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
at spritesheet.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Java Result: 1
```

error!

This is my code:

```
package spritesheet;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

BufferedImage sprite;
  private final Color Color;

public Main(Color white){
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color=white); 
    init();
}


private void init(){
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
    try {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("spritesheet.png");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);

    sprite = ss.grabSprite(0, 0, 16, 16);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(sprite, 100, 100, null);
    repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main Main = new Main();
}
}
```

This code aims to display a still image on a white background however it either throws an error or shows a transparent background. It then bugs out and annoys me. :(
What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your class like this

```
Main Main = new Main();
```

But you need to pass a parameter to it because you defined it as

```
public Main(Color white) { ... }
```

You could change it to

```
Main Main = new Main(Color.WHITE);
```

and

```
public Main(Color c) {
   setSize(800, 600);
   setVisible(true);
   setResizable(true);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   Color = c;
   setBackground(Color); 
   init();
}
```

### Edit

You can do 2 things now. Either make your `Color`variable `static` like this:

```
private static Color Color;
```

or change your `Main` constructor to

```
public Main() {
   setSize(800, 600);
   setVisible(true);
   setResizable(true);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   Color = Color.WHITE;
   setBackground(Color); 
   init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the compiler spits this error out:run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable Color cannot be referenced from a static context
 at spritesheet.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Java Result: 1

Comment: The error you are getting says that your `main` entry point is `static` and can only use `static` variables. Either make `color` static`or change your code like in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you don't define any custom constructor, the compiler will add a default constructor that doesn't take in any argument.

Since you have a custom constructor `Main(Color white)` (I suggest that you name the parameter "color" instead - any color can be assigned), this is the only constructor in `Main` class. So you must call your custom constructor by providing a `Color object` as argument.