# Formal and Actual, How to identify?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what the formal and actual variables are in the calls to the void

When "hello" is called twice, The formal/actual variables called are "first,second,ch" and "x,y,z" But when the second hello is called I can only tell that the actual parameters are "x,y,'S'" what would the formal parameters be to those can't

Thanks in advance

```
public class parameters
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
    int x;
    double y;
    char z;
    //more code here
    //This call
    hello(x,y,z);
    //and this one
    hello(x + 2, y - 3.5, 'S');

public static void hello(int first, double second, char ch)
{
 int num
 double ;
 //more code
}
```

}

Comment: Java is not C... what are you really asking? And, your code is not valid.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by formal and actual.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c4/s3.html#subroutines.3.2

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Other than the missing variable name for `double`, this is valid Java and the missing initializer for x,y,z

Comment: @staticx **And** the missing semicolon for `num`. **And** the missing close bracket at the end of main. In comparison, the lowercase class name is merely stylistic.

Comment: It's the first time that I hear these terms: formal, actual; specially with this usage.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Absolutely, there are many problems with this code but it's surely not C :)

Comment: @mok: It's used mostly in an academic setting.. no one in the real world uses it probably ever

Comment: @staticx True. I was thinking there was some K&R style variable declaration going on there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Fair enough :)

Comment: @staticx- So I should have heard them for sure, up to now :) I think he means `argument` and `parameter`.

Comment: @mok: Nope, formal and actual are real terms used by Java. Some error messages use that terminology. Parameter and Argument are used interchangeably. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860203/actual-and-formal-argument

Comment: @staticx They are used interchangeably but they are not the same : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kewt1b3.aspx

Comment: @mok: Ok, please don't link to an MSDN article on Visual Basic, when we are dealing with Java :)

Comment: @staticx- Ok,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , Sorry for all the errors. I was just about to go to work. I got home just now! Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal parameters in `hello(...)` are `int first`, `double second`, and `char ch`.

The actual parameters are `x`, `y`, and `z` or rather what is contained within them.

> A formal parameter must be a name, that is, a simple identifier. A
>   formal parameter is very much like a variable, and -- like a variable
>   -- it has a specified type such as int, boolean, or String. An actual parameter is a value, and so it can be specified by any expression,
>   provided that the expression computes a value of the correct type. The
>   type of the actual parameter must be one that could legally be
>   assigned to the formal parameter with an assignment statement.

So as the above quote states, it doesn't matter if the **actual parameter** is an expression as long as it computes the correct type to match the **formal parameter**.

More on formal and actual parameters here: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c4/s3.html#subroutines.3.2

Comment: Thanks! I understand that part but the second call is where i'm confused, What would be the parameters there.

Comment: @Recontroop: See my latest

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong but for the second call the " x , y , and 'S'" will correspond to the following (int first, double second, char ch" in the void hello?

Comment: @Recontroop: Right, it says "An actual parameter is a value and so it can be specified in an expression...". `x + 2` is an expression (which matches the formal parameter `int`).. `y - 3.5` is an expression (which matches the formal parameter `double`).. `S` is an actual parameter matching to the formal parameter `char`